# How to stabilize the magnetic levitation system?

Tags: electromagnetism, pid-controller, hall-effect, arduino-uno

I have asked similar question before also but want to try again - [Not able to levitate magnet for magnetic levitation project](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/429840/not-able-to-levitate-magnet-for-magnetic-levitation-project)

I followed everything from this project but still, the magnet is not levitating - https://www.hackster.io/jsirgado/magnet-levitation-with-arduino-eeeee4

The best I can do is to make the magnet jump up and down fast but it never levitates. Have tried changing PID setting from the project as aggressive and mild but still didn't achieve the final result.

I need advice from an expert to tell me what I am doing wrong here. All components are in good condition and 5v electromagnet is strong enough.

So what am I missing here?

Comment: If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. Do not create a duplicate question.

Comment: You **didn't** follow everything from the project page.  You made changes, and you don't understand the effects of those changes.

Comment: Are u talking about TIP120 transistor? does that make a big difference?